# Number column is not showing using the ngx-highlightJs in angular 8

Tags: angular8

Given data are some main HTML page and provider of the module

```
<pre>
    <code [highlight]="previewText" [lineNumbers]="true"></code>
</pre>

providers: [
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: <HighlightOptions>{
        lineNumbers: true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**In app.module.ts file**

```
import { HighlightModule, HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS, HighlightOptions } from 'ngx-highlightjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
     HighlightModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: <HighlightOptions>{
        lineNumbers: true
      }
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HighlightResult } from 'ngx-highlightjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 // response: HighlightResult;

  code = `const index=0` 
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<pre><code [highlight]="code" [lineNumbers]="true" ></code></pre>
```